# Finding solutions for $\sin(z)=\sin(2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

having some difficulty wrapping my head around how to methodically do this style of question:

*Find all solutions $z\in ℂ$ for $\sin(z)=\sin(2)$*

I attempted to solve this by using the identity,

$\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)=\sin(2)$,

so that,

$\sin(x)\cosh(y)=\sin(2)$ and $\cos(x)\sinh(y)=0$,

but this seemed to lead to a dead end, so I'm unsure as to what the next step should be...

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hint: The second equation has soln either $y=0,x\in\Bbb R$ or $y\in\Bbb R,x=\frac{2n+1}2\pi$. Which of these work for the first equation? Does substituting into the first equation restrict the ranges of some of those variables (i.e. where I put $\in\Bbb R$)?

Comment: No need for identities: recall the definition of $sin(z):=(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i$ and let $z=x+iy$.

Comment: So if I put $y=0$ then in the first equation I have $\sin(x)=\sin(2)$ which seems to be only a slight improvement on the initial problem?
If I do $x=π/2, 3π/2...$ then we get $\pm\cosh(y)=\sin(2)$ right?

Comment: @speedystacks It is high-school level that $\sin(a)=\sin(b)$ iff $a=2k\pi+b $ or $a=(2k+1)\pi-b$ for $a,b$ **reals**

Comment: fair enough, I don't remember learning that specifically in high school - do you have the proof? Also I have other questions like $sin(z)=sinh(2)$ so if I could work out a method that also works for those it would be more useful.

Comment: @speedystacks see the answer by Szeto for the best method to solve these in general - it is done with a general $k$ there. See the other answers for more depth on the above comments.

Comment: @speedystacks The proof is only technical; have a look at the graph of $x\mapsto\sin(x)$ and observe where a horizontal line intersects it. Even for problems involving $\sinh$, all you have to do is recall the definitions and work the details with the Real and Imaginary parts equations :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've got it now... finally! You've all been really helpful so thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP seems confused, I am providing the details.

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\sin(z)=\sin(2)$. Then $\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=\sin(2)$, therefore, if $z=x+iy$, $e^{ix-y}-e^{-ix+y}=2i\sin(2)$, hence $e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))-e^y(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))=2i\sin(2)$. Real and imaginary parts have to be equal, so one gets $(e^{-y}-e^y)\cos(x)=0$ and $e^{-y}\sin(x)+e^y\sin(x)=2\sin(2)$. The first one yields either $y=0$ or $x=k\pi+\pi/2$, but $x=k\pi+\pi/2$ is ruled out by the second equation, since $e^t+e^{-t}\geq2$ . 
So $y=0$ and the second equation gives $\sin(x)=\sin(2)$, so $x=2k\pi+2$ or $x=(2k+1)\pi-2$

Answer (score 2):

This is a different approach to the other answers, which use complex exponentials to solve. I am following up on the comment I put.

As you said in a comment, if $y=0$, then $\sin x=\sin 2$. Since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic, $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(x)$. So we have $x=2+2\pi n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$.

It is worth check if the alternative solution works - $x=\frac{2n+1}2\pi,y\in\Bbb R$. In this case, $\sin(x)=(-1)^n$, so we need $\cosh y=\pm \sin2$. But $\cosh y>1\,\,\,\,\forall y$ and $|\sin 2|<1$. So there is no solution here. Hence the solutions above are the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}=k$$
Let $x=e^{iz}$,
$$x^2-2ikx-1=0$$
$$x=ik\pm \sqrt{1-k^2}$$
$$z=-i(\ln (ik\pm \sqrt{1-k^2})+2n\pi i)= -i\ln (ik\pm \sqrt{1-k^2})+2n\pi $$

For $k=\sin(m)$
$$ik\pm \sqrt{1-k^2}=\pm \cos(m)+i\sin(m)=\pm e^{\pm im}$$

So
$$z=-i(\ln(\pm 1)\pm im)+2n\pi$$
where we define $\ln(1)=0$ and $\ln(-1)=i\pi$.

**A quicker approach:**

Make use of the identities:

$$\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$$
$$\sin(x)=\sin(x+2n\pi)$$

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful :)

Comment: @speedystacks Then could you kindly tap on the tick to make it green?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
  & \text{This problem still can be solved following your procedure}: \\ 
 & \cos \left( x \right)\sinh \left( y \right)=0\Rightarrow \cos \left( x \right)=0\ OR\ \sinh \left( y \right)=0 \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & If\sinh \left( y \right)=0,\ then\ y=0\ ,and\ hence\  \\ 
 & \sin \left( x \right)\cosh \left( y \right)=\sin \left( x \right)\cosh \left( 0 \right) \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad =\sin \left( x \right)\times 1 \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad =\sin \left( x \right) \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \Rightarrow \sin \left( x \right)=\sin \left( 2 \right)\Rightarrow x=2+2n\pi . \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & If\ \cos \left( x \right)=0,\ then\ \sin \left( x \right)=\pm \sqrt{1-\cos {{\left( x \right)}^{2}}}=\pm \sqrt{1-{{0}^{2}}}=\pm 1,and\ hence \\ 
 & \ \sin \left( x \right)\cosh \left( y \right)=\pm \cosh \left( y \right)=\sin \left( 2 \right) \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \,\,\Rightarrow \ \cosh \left( y \right)=\pm \sin \left( 2 \right)\  \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \,\,\Rightarrow \ \cosh \left( y \right)=\sin \left( 2 \right)\ since\ \cosh \left( y \right),\sin \left( 2 \right)>0.\  \\ 
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \,\,\Rightarrow y={{\cosh }^{-1}}\left( \sin \left( 2 \right) \right). \\ 
 &  \\ 
 & Finally\ z=\left( 2+2n\pi  \right)+i{{\cosh }^{-1}}\left( \sin \left( 2 \right) \right) \\ 
\end{align}
$$